# Groovy @singleton is not working properly

Tags: groovy, singleton

Below is the code that I am trying execute as singleton

*MyResourceBundleSingleton.groovy* // groovy class

```
@Singleton
class MyResourceBundleSingleton {

    public ResourceBundle getResourceBundle () {
        return someService.getMyResourceBundle() // this bundle is returned by calling a separate method
    }
```

*MyResourceBundleSingleton.java* // java class

```
public class MyResourceBundleSingleton {

    private MyResourceBundleSingleton () {
    }

    private static MyResourceBundleSingleton myBundle;

    public static MyResourceBundleSingleton getMyResourceBundleSingletonInstance() {
        if (myBundle == null) {
            synchronized (MyResourceBundleSingleton.class) {
                if (myBundle == null) {
                    myBundle = new MyResourceBundleSingleton();
                }
            }
        }
        return myBundle;
    }

    public ResourceBundle getResourceBundle () {
        return someService.getMyResourceBundle() // this bundle is returned by calling a separate method
    }
}
```

// *Calling groovy*

```
MyResourceBundleSingleton.instance.getResourceBundle()
```

// *Calling java*

```
MyResourceBundleSingleton.getMyResourceBundleSingletonInstance().getResourceBundle()
```

Both groovy and java code calls the same method `someService.getMyResourceBundle()`. In java code only once the .properites file is loaded and the same file is returned for every call, which is proper way of singleton.
Whereas in groovy by using @singleton when ever there is a change in .properties file the changed file is returned.I dont know why this is happening.I was expecting it to return the same .properties file.
Am I missing something in groovy code.??

Answer (score 1):

You're calling the service on each call to `getResourceBundle()` in both singletons.  Assuming this loads a properties file, there's no reason in either case for it to be cached.  If the Java version is returning a cached version, there is something else saving it not shown in your code.

Comment: I modified groovy code to initialize the resource bundle inside the constructor. Then it started working fine as singleton(i.e., loads only once and doesnt reflect the changes made in file until i restart).But for the java code there is no caching it is the same code that I am using, I dont know why it is returning the same instance. Technically it should return me the current updated properties file. But it is not, it gives me back the same file I am wondering how??!!!Anyways i will brainstorm it.